# Entity Framework interceptor for log Debug.Write web.config

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to create a Debug.Write logger on my project while development time. So I can do this on code configuration like this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Action<string> print = message => Debug.WriteLine(message);
        Database.Log =print;
    }
```

But I want to add this on web.config file as entity framework section element. Is there any way to do this?

```
<interceptors> 
  <interceptor type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogger, EntityFramework"> 
      ??????
  </interceptor> 
</interceptors>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the interceptor either by using config file or code-based configuration.

See the following on how to do this (includes demo):

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-interception.aspx

Assuming you have the following interceptor

```
 EFCommandInterceptor: IDbCommandInterceptor
```

**Config**

```
<entityFramework>
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor type="EF6DBFirstTutorials.EFCommandInterceptor, EF6DBFirstTutorials">
        </interceptor>
    </interceptors>
</entityFramework>
```

**Code**

```
public class EF6CodeConfig : DbConfiguration
{
    public EF6CodeConfig()
    {
        this.AddInterceptor(new EFCommandInterceptor());
    }
}
```